# Why download a Yosemite .dmg when I can create my own?

Tags: macos, vmware, dmg, bootable-disk

Having a Mac I wanted to know can't I just make my own .dmg file using AutoDMG? Instead of finding some random file on the Internet and hoping its not infected? Is there any other software that would allow me to make a Yosemite image. Not a boot drive. By making my image file I can use it on my VMware software right?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to just create a Yosemite installer DMG to install Yosemite on your VMWare software? You would need to create a bootable Yosemite installer.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you not want to download a Yosemite installer directly from Apple?  If you don't have access, I am sure there are people who could download it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Mac App Store download of OS X 10.10, Yosemite, directly with VMware Fusion. There is no need to create your own disk image, `.dmg`, unless you need to customise the installed files.

Within VMware Fusion's **Select the Installation Method** window, select **Install from disc or image** and choose the OS X installer from your files.

[image: VMware Fusion - Select the Installation Method]

## Downloading OS X

If you need to download an older version of OS X, sign up as an Apple developer and use the Software Downloads to obtain the legacy installer.